# How to make shell script as a service in RHEL7?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a below script which basically does start|start|stop|restart

Script name amr.sh
eg: how do i execute now:  ./amr.sh start

I want this script as service:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: AMR Service shell script
# Author: NSK

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app
    # example: daemon program_name &
        echo "Starting AMR service..... "
        daemon /root/amr/bin/LoggerServer &
        echo "Starting Logger...."
        sleep 2
        daemon /root/amr/bin/mediaController -i 192.168.117.119 &
        echo "Starting Mediacontroller....."
        sleep 4
        daemon /root/amr/bin/mstdaemon --daemon &
        echo "Starting Media Streamer...."
        sleep 4
        daemon /root/amr/bin/pcdaemon --daemon -i ens192 -f "'udp && portrange 3000-8000 && not(src host localhost)'" &
        sleep 3
        echo "Starting Packetcapture...."
        daemon /root/amr/bin/stund &
        echo "Starting Stun..."
        daemon /root/amr/bin/tdaemon &
        sleep 2
        echo "Starting Transcoder...."
        status LoggerServer
        status mediaController
        status mstdaemon
        status pcdaemon
        status stund
        status tdaemon
        echo "Started AMR services. "
}
stop() {
    # code to stop app
    # example: killproc program_name
        echo "Stopping AMR service..... "
        killproc LoggerServer
        echo "Stoping Logger..... "
        killproc mediaController
        echo "Stoping MediaController...."
        killproc mstdaemon
        echo "Stoping Mediastreamer..."
        killproc pcdaemon
        echo "Stoping Packet Capture....."
        killproc stund
        echo "Stoping Stun....."
        killproc tdaemon
        echo "Stoping Transcoder....."
        status LoggerServer
        status mediaController
        status mstdaemon
        status pcdaemon
        status stund
        status tdaemon
        echo "Stopped AMR service "
}

case "$1" in
    start)
       start
        echo "success AMR server startup"
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here

      # example: status program_name
        status LoggerServer
        status mediaController
        status mstdaemon
        status pcdaemon
        status stund
        status tdaemon
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Read up on systemd.  You just need to create a systemd config and put it in the right place.  The googles will show you the way.

Answer (score 0):

First, copy your script in `/usr/sbin/` directory.

```
/usr/sbin/amr
```

Than, create a unit file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` directory.

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/amr.service
```

File contents should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=AMR Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/amr start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/amr restart
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/amr stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**start service**

```
systemctl start amr
```

**check status**

```
systemctl status amr
```

**stop service**

```
systemctl stop amr
```

**restart service**

```
systemctl reload amr
```

**enable on boot**

```
systemctl enable amr
```

**disable on boot**

```
systemctl disable amr
```